# Why does <nav style=“position:sticky;”> not work when inside a <header> element?

Tags: html, css

Simply removing the  at the top of the  would help the element stick to the top:0px; of the page or  would also work. Semantically I’ve read articles saying to place  at the top of the  so webpages can read your code better or for accessibility purposes. Why would position:sticky; not work for navbars inside of a  element? This seems like it would be more of a common problem and haven’t found anything online to help out. Thanks!!

I tried absolutely everything in so many different ways and the  just simply needs to be removed in order for position:sticky; to work properly.

Comment: Please show your code